# How to create native ios react-native module?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I write react-native app with ios native codes,
then I want to extract one ui component (include swift code) as a  cocoa-touch-framework so that other project/people can use it easily.

here is some simplification of what I have done.

```
$react-native init FooLibContainer             #create a new react-native project
$cd FooLibContainer
$react-native new-library --name FooLib        # create a library
$cp -r  node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FooLib ../
$cd ../FooLib                                   # copy as a standalone library
$open FooLib.xcodeproj                          #open with xcode


$ # build FooLib target in xcode, Failed by 

`.../FooLib/FooLib.h:1:9: 'React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found`  


$ # add react dependency in package.json

  "dependencies": {
    "react": ">=15.4.0",
    "react-native": ">=0.40"
  }


$ npm install
$ react-native link


$ open FooLib.xcodeproj # open project again with xcode
$ nothing changed, same error
```

Can the lib be compiled alone?
I also tried some libraries in github, like [react-native-camera](https://github.com/lwansbrough/react-native-camera),
git clone
npm install
react-native link

and also get build errors.

What is correct approach to successfully compile an react-native module?

Comment: You got an answer for this? Me too facing same problem.

Comment: cocoapods works.